# D3 force layout stable detect

Tags: layout, d3.js, transform, force-layout

I need to detect the stability of force layout, for example, when it transform coordinates, add a loading animation on the page.

After it finished, then remove the loading animation.

The 'stable' are not that precisely, but should be detect the graph almost stable.

What should I do? Any suggestions or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-stop) says that the stability is felt when `alpha` goes below the threshold value (default value is `0.1`) so you could just listen to this value and workout. I will try to post a `fiddle` on this soon.

Comment: The alpha goes to 0 if force layout stopped